# How to rotate a drawable by ObjectAnimator?

Tags: android, rotation, drawable, objectanimator

Alphaing a drawable  work well like this:

```
if(mAlphaAnimation == null){
        mAlphaAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "alpha", 0.0f,1.0f).setDuration(TARGET_ANIM_ALPHA_DURATION);
        mAlphaAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        mAlphaAnimation.setStartDelay(TARGET_ANIM_ALPHA_DELAY_BASE*power);
        mAlphaAnimation.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        mAlphaAnimation.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        mAlphaAnimation.addUpdateListener(this);
 }
```

But if I want rotate a drawable like below , it don's work.

```
private void createRotateAnim(float fromDegress,float toDegress,int duration){
    if(mRotateAnimation == null){
        mRotateAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "rotation",fromDegress,toDegress).setDuration(duration);
        mRotateAnimation.setStartDelay(100);
        mRotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        mRotateAnimation.addUpdateListener(this);
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me to fix this issue, or these is any other way to create a rotation drawable animation .

I am sorry to my poor English.

Comment: I wanna change a drawable status through touch event,the drawable is a single drawable,not a drawable list.For example, change a drawable alpha value according to moving distance on screen. And this function have finished. Then, i wanna change a drawable direction according to moving angle. In other words, rotate the drawable according to the angle. These drawables will be draw on the same view.

I wanna to know a ObjectAnimator object with rotation property can rotate a drawable or not. perhaps, it can rotate,because a imageview can rotate a drawable used to background drawable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Using ObjectAnimator to translate a View with fractional values of the View's dimension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854940/android-using-objectanimator-to-translate-a-view-with-fractional-values-of-the)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this simple Rotation Animation applied to a image.

```
 ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimage);
 RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(180, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,    
 0.5f,  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
  rotate.setDuration(500);
 imageview.startAnimation(rotate);
```

This answer is just for a sake of question, it is correct that Clickable area will be different than `View`'s current position. Please check this question for making clickable area correct. [Button is not clickable after TranslateAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067778/button-is-not-clickable-after-translateanimation)

Comment: Thank you. but I don't wanna put the drawble into other view,like ImageView and so on, but wanna draw it on a subclass of view(NOT ViewGroup).

Comment: @marine8888 I think your mistaken, `ImageView` is simply a subclass of `View` and not `ViewGroup` (Which itself is a subclass of `View`). You could create your own subclass of `View` and render the drawable onto a canvas, however this would do the same job as an `ImageView`.

Answer (score 76):

Try with `ObjectAnimator` instead.

```
ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

ObjectAnimator imageViewObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageview ,
                    "rotation", 0f, 360f);
            imageViewObjectAnimator.setDuration(1000); // miliseconds
            imageViewObjectAnimator.start();
```

**EDIT**
*Since this question draw some attention let me to explain why to use `ObjectAnimator` instead of other Transition animators*

The thing about using `ObjectAnimator` is that it's moving both the visible and the clickable area of the item, if you use another animation method, for example Transition Animation or some other Animators, and let's say if you want to move the `Button` from the bottom left of the screen to the top left, it will only move the visible area but not the `Button` itself, the clickable area will still be on the previous position, in this case the clickable area will still be on the bottom left instead of the top left where you moved the button.

If you do the same with `ObjectAnimator`, both the visible area, and the clickable area will move the the desired location.