# Android rotation animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a problem and I just can't manage to find a solution that works. 
So, here is my problem. I have to make an `ImageView` to rotate itself, to 90 degree on orientation change.
I did that, and the image is actually rotating pretty awesome, but when the animation finishes, the image reset itself to previous position.

Here is the code I used to rotate the image:

```
   Matrix matrix = mImageView.getImageMatrix();
                    RectF dst = new RectF();
                    matrix.mapRect(dst, new RectF(mImageView.getDrawable().getBounds()));
                    mAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, -90.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                    mAnimation.setDuration(5000);
                    mImageView.startAnimation(mAnimation);
                    mImageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                    mCurrentOrientation = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this to animation persist after it has been done:

```
mAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
```

Comment: Thanks :) I know that there is something easy like this :P

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is set the imageview to an already rotated version of the image and then rotate it from -90 to 0 degrees.  That will work with the API you are already using.  If you make the two calls, one right after  it will work correctly without stutter.

The other option is to use a later API version.  The Object Animator animations do not return the view to it's original position. More on this here.

[How to rotate a drawable by ObjectAnimator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039265/how-to-rotate-a-drawable-by-objectanimator)

The code is simple, but this doesn't work with gingerbread.