# Rotating and scaling a drawable using android ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, scale, android-4.4-kitkat, objectanimator, animatorset

I saw a few [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039265/how-to-rotate-a-drawable-by-objectanimator) of using an ObjectAnimator to rotate and scale an `ImageView`.

However I want to rotate and scale a `Drawable` for API below 21 (So I cannot use `AnimatedVectorDrawable`).

It doesn't have `setRotation` and `setScaleX` like an `ImageView` has.

Do I have any simple way to achieve this?

```
rotationObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rotationDrawable, "rotation", 0f, 360f);
rotationObjectAnimator.setDuration(1000); // miliseconds
rotationObjectAnimator.start();

scaleObjectAnimator =
    ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(
        scaleDrawable,
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 0.5f),
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 0.5f));

final AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
animatorSet.playSequentially(rotationObjectAnimator, scaleObjectAnimator);
```