# how to play sound in Rollette game to each section cross android

Tags: android

I am making a Rollette game and I want to play sound in each crossing section like if 1 is crossing it should find some trigger or collision detection and ping one tick sound. My problem is that I am not able to find the collision detection on image. Below is the approaches that I have done.

1. I have taken LayoutView and placed a Rollette wheel image inside it.
2. In each section (0-9) has taken a green small button which will be used to detect the collision with the arrow. Once it collides there will be a Tick sound with up-down animation in arrow. (Image attached).

Problem.

1. I am not able to find the new co-ordinate of views in each rotation. It is returning the same static location every time and hence collision is never happening.

Rotation Code..

```
    final RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 360f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setDuration(10000);
    rotate.setFillAfter(true);
```

Collision detection code...

```
    Rect arrowBtnRect = new Rect();
    arrowBtn.getGlobalVisibleRect(arrowBtnRect);


    Rect btn0Rect = new Rect();
    btn0.getGlobalVisibleRect(btn0Rect);

   if(arrowBtnRect.intersect(btn0Rect)) {
       System.out.println("Collision detected "+numberSelected);
       numberSelected = "0";
       return true;
   }
```

[image]

Comment: I think you have check collisions the other way. Not by button's position, but by the angle of Roulette view after according each button position with it's relative angle to Roulette before starting animation...

Comment: Please elaborate more, I am checking collision with one button which is present in green in each section corner with the arrow button which is in blue. Finding both view rect from the getGlobalVisibleRect function and checking the intersection point.

Comment: getGlobalVisibleRect gives you the 'static' position of view since it's not really moving. See my posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your idea is brilliant!

But I have certain remarks on your approach:

- setFillAfter() is not helping, according to documentations:

> If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed will persist when it is finished.

- I recommend using `ObjectAnimator` instead of `RotateAnimation`. While `RotateAnimation` is just making the view looks as if it is rotating until you call fillAfter (which happens after animation stops), `ObjectAnimator` makes the view really change its actual angle while rotating. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29465710/10005752

**Usage:**

```
    Random random = new Random(); 
    float randomAngle = (float) (random.nextInt(360) + 1); 
    ObjectAnimator rouletteAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rouletteView, View.ROTATION, 0f, randomAngle);
    rouletteAnimator.setDuration(10000);
    rouletteAnimator.start();
```

---

Also, to elaborate more on my comment I recommend that get all angles that have buttons on them before starting animating, and when animation starts keep using `rouletteView.getRotation();` to check what angle is at the top.

Example:

[image: Roulette example]

`Button1` is at angle 90 and `rouletteView` is rotating Counter Clockwise. Then if `rouletteView.getRotation() == 360 - 90` is true then `Button1` is touching the arrow.

I hope I'm clear!

Comment: Thanks for reply... will try this logic.. could you please tell me how will I make a random rotation of the wheel in ObjectAnimator because every time it is stopping on the same number.

Comment: I am no sure I understand what you mean by "random" rotation, do you need a random number to use as an degree/angle? Or a random number of rotations? Or something else?

Comment: I want. to rotate the wheel and it should stop on any random number of sections.

Comment: See my answer now, I added a sample code with `ObjectAnimator` that does the same as your previous `RotateAnimation` code.

Comment: Your reference code is always stoping on the initial position of the image, example on every time it is stoping on 0th sec. I think because of 360 deg rotation. I want it to stop on randomly. It should rotate 360 but should stop at random.

Comment: I added a code of CountDownTimer timer and when timer is complete it is calling rotate.cancel() method to stop the rotation.

Comment: Hi Ajay, see my latest edit, I added a Random number that will be between 1 to 360.

Comment: Hi Khalid.. thanks for answer.. I implemented the logic and I getting the values but some time because of below error calculated value is not reflecting..
"Skipped 96 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread"

I implemented this approx logic to get the current sector and collision --- rouletteView.getRotation() == 360 - 90 ..