# ImageButton is not Clickable after implementing animation

Tags: java, android, animation

In an android application I am implementing an `Animation` on an `ImageButton`. After the animation the button remains at it's last frame but it is only clickable at it's initial position, I have Implemented an `BounceInterpolation` animation by these line of code in my main .java `Activity`

```
TranslateAnimation translation;
translation = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 0F, 0f, 200);
translation.setStartOffset(150);
translation.setDuration(100);
translation.setFillAfter(true);
translation.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
mTourButton.startAnimation(translation);
```

I don't know how to update the the `ImageButton` parameters. Most of the solutions are for the xml implemented animations. I didn't find any solution. I am tired now please help.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067778/button-is-not-clickable-after-translateanimation

Comment: I have tried all the 3-4 solutions listed since I asked the question but people I just want to update the parameters to the last frame of animation. I think setLayoutParams() method can be helpful but I don't even know what should i pass as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `onTouch()` to handle your clicks.

```
imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
            {
            // Do whatever you want here.
            }
        return true;
    }
});
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Better add `onClick` in `XML`:

```
 <ImageButton
    android:onClick="doSomethingMethod"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Press `ALT+ENTER` on `doSomethingMethod` and `Create 'doSomethingMethod(View)' in 'Activity'`

This will create a method like `onClickListener` in your `Activity`.

Hope it helps!